# Cython causes python interpreter crashed with Python objects creation

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management, malloc, cython, cythonize

We have Cython wrapper developed for C++ bindings and Python client is consuming the cython wrapper.
Python interpreter is getting crashed sometimes(segmentation) or not working properly when we create python objects and calls python client func(which calls Cython func).

```
cpdef Cythonfunc(
                                self, 
                                url,
                                content,
                                content_len,
                                request_headers,
                                response_headers):
        cdef DATA data = {}
        cdef RESULT DRESULT= {}
        cdef TYPE _type = DEFAULT
        
        cdef int la = 1
        cdef unsigned int ant_mask=0x00
        cdef int url_len = len(url)
        cdef int request_headers_len = len(request_headers)
        cdef int response_headers_len = len(response_headers)

        data.URL=url
        data .URLLen=url_len
        data.Content=content
       
        ret = CcaScanHttpTransaction(p1, &data, &RESULT )
        if ret < 0:
            print(f"Failed to scan the given url, Received status code {ret} from CCA")
            return {"status": "Failed", "message": f"Failed to scan the url:{url} CcaReasonCode: {ret}"}
```

Python client:

```
 def http_transaction_scan(self, transaction=None):
        
        if not transaction or not self.is_valid_request(transaction.keys(), ['url', 'content']):
            raise CcaInvalidRequestData(f'Invalid request data, transaction: {transaction}')
        try:
            url = transaction.get('url')
            content = transaction.get('content', b'') or b''
            content_len = len(content)
            request_headers = transaction.get('request_headers', {})
            response_headers = transaction.get('response_headers', {})
            results = self.cca.Cythonfunc(url=url, content=content, content_len=content_len, request_headers=request_headers, response_headers=response_headers)
            if 'status' in results and results.get('status') == 'Failed':
                raise CcaHttpScanError(f'Failed to scan the http transaction, msg: {results}')
            return results
        except Exception as exp:
            print(f'Error while performing the cca_client CcaScanHttpTransaction, Reason: {exp}')
```

```
test.py

import cca_client
import boto3

cca_obj = cca_client.client.PyCca()
cca_obj.load_cca_databases()

import tracemalloc
tracemalloc.start()

try:
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_client = boto3.client('sqs', region_name=aws_region)
except:
pass

exploit_html = "big html page content"
url_1 = '\<URL\>'
transaction = {
'url': url_1,
'content': exploit_html,
'request_headers': b'',
'response_headers': b''
}
snapshot1 = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()


res_1 = cca_obj.http_transaction_scan(transaction)
print(res_1)

snapshot2 = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
top_stats = snapshot2.compare_to(snapshot1, 'lineno')

# top_stats = snapshot.statistics('lineno')

print("\[ Top 10 \]")
for stat in top_stats\[:10\]:
print(stat)
```

Above test.py works fine if we don't create s3_client object and raises segmentation issues or return partial results otherwise.

Does importing the python client module which has the imported Cython module causing the issues, any suggestions would help a lot, thanks.

Tried with all other ways but still no luck, it causes segmentation issues still.

**PROBLEM:**
If I import cython module X into a python module Y and then import this python module Y into another Python module Z, then it works without any issues.
But If I import any other libraries like requests or boto3 or any other libraries into module Z along Y import, then my script raises the Segmentation issues(python interpreter crashed)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for point this our @BlueRobin, added a problem section to my question now, please let me know if we need any other details.

Comment: This needs an [mre]. It's currently completely unanswerable